# Why does the onClick() function takes Parameters instead of Arguments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, apk

I am new to Android Development and I found that while using the setOnClickListener() Method the onClick function takes a parameter instead of an argument. why is onClick function's syntax is like user defined function? I am very much confused. Below is an image that reflects my point of view.
[image: Argument vs Parameter]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView display = findViewById(R.id.Display);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            display.setText("Ravikiran");
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Here in the above code i am confused with the part of the code which is mentioned below.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            display.setText("Ravikiran");
        }
```

Comment: That is because `public void onClick(View v) { /* ... */}` **is** a function definition. The function that you define is later called (from android code) when the button is clicked.

Comment: `OnClickListener` is an interface, `onClick` is not a user defined function it is defined by the interface. Since the `setOnClickListener` is expecting an interface you need to implement all of the defined functions in the interface